# Kotlin - How to open link of Telegram group into Telegram app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio-3.0

I have a group [link](https://t.me/name_group) of Telegram. What I want is when i click on the button them i want to open that like into the telegram app instead of browser(Currently it is opened in browser).

Here is the code that i have tried to make it possible :

```
val group_telegram = Intent (ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://t.me/name_group"))
startActivity(group_telegram)
```

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want to open that group page?

Answer (score 3):

You can check if telegram app is installed on user device by using `setPackage()` method like below.

```
val telegram = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://t.me/name_group"))
        telegram.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger")
        startActivity(telegram)
```